# Unanswered Bounty question

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, bounty

I asked a question that didn't receive enough attention, so I started a bounty. It remained unanswered for a week, and my bounty automatically closed, but I didn't get my points back. How is this helpful? I didn't any answers or even hints (I didn't even receive more attention), so my bounty was basically wasted. Now I want to start a new bounty with more points, but don't have enough. How is this an encouraging feature?

Comment: I gave you a bit attention ;-). Tried to solve it as well but I guess it's difficult to resolve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the risk you take with a bounty. Once the bounty is set you lose the points.

No one is under any obligation to answer your question and if no one knows the answer then they're not going to answer bounty or not.

I can only suggest that you add any extra information you've managed to find from your continued investigations - you are still actively looking for a solution aren't you?

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found more than I already have [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/37184/google-calendar-colorize-weekends-in-firefox)

Comment: I suggest you try and ask at [SO], since there's some programming involved.

Comment: @pnuts but those are edge cases that aren't relevant to this cases

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see your question answered. I would say (in this particular case...):

> Cut Asymptotically some slack and give him his 50 rep. back (upvote question on WebApp)!!

Here is the Q&A : [Google Calendar colorize weekends in Firefox](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/37184/29140)

Comment: My answer leaves everybody indifferent? Meta is about voting to express your opinion.